# Flask cookiecutter models don't generate migrations

Tags: python, flask, cookiecutter

New to the world of python, was recommended to try [cookiecutter-flask](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask) but bumped into a problem:

I generated a migration "manually" rather then having it based on a model. After I realised that models can be used to generate migrations like the one that comes "stock" with the cookiecutter - I removed my manual migration but cannot seem to get the model to generate a migration file.

In app.py

```
from project import commands, public, user, category

def register_blueprints(app):
"""Register Flask blueprints."""
app.register_blueprint(public.views.blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(user.views.blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(category.views.blueprint) <- my model
return None
```

In the views

```
blueprint = Blueprint('category', __name__, url_prefix='/categories', static_folder='../static')
```

My routes appear to be detected

```
#flask urls
/categories/                                  category.categories          
/categories/static/<path:filename>            category.static
```

But when I run

```
#flask db migrate
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'users'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'roles'
```

It does not seem to be able to detect categories model, and I am lost as to what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh so the problem ended up being this:

I based my model on the Users model that comes with the cookiecutter. In the view we never import the Users model where it apparently should be imported, instead the mechanism seems to rely on public/views.py importing it

```
from project.user.models import User
```

And because in register_blueprints() public gets loaded before, we already have access to the User model by the time we come to deal with the user views.

So tl;dr it needs to be imported in the whatevermodel/views.py as

```
from project.category.models import Category
```

Which sounds to me like a bit too much magic and reliance on public being loaded before users...